# Proxmox for enterprise environment

Tags: virtualization, vmware-esxi, proxmox

I'm in a process of upgrading existing server infrastructure witch consists of couple of self-built servers running XEN.

For management reasons XEN is not ideal, because requires advance console knowledge, editing VM config files from terminal etc.

All things considered WEB based VM management would be preferable backed by reliable hardware e.g. "real server".

Our company needs are not hundreds of VM's so for cost effectiveness I'm looking into other free solutions and Proxmox does stand out.

Does anyone successfully uses Proxmox as virtualization platform for enterprise or better bet is just pay the price of VMWARE.

Please share your toughts\experiences.

Comment: Server Fault does not do product recommendations. Establish some criteria, make a short list that meets those, try each on the list.

Comment: Why not Hyper-V Core host (free)?